# urllib urlopen not fetching second time around

Tags: python

When opening a url and trying to do it again it doesn't actually fetch anything the second time around.

Any idea why?

```
def Titles():
    titleread = titlerequest.read()
    Headlines = '<title>.+</title>'
    NewsHeadlines = re.findall(Headlines, titleread)

    Headlines = [T.replace('<title>', '') for T in sHeadlines]
    Headlines = [T.replace('</title>', '') for T in Headlines]
    return Headlines
```

Comment: Not particularly related, but I notice you're attempting to parse some HTML content with a regex. [You do not want to parse html with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1):

Once you've read from a server and it's delivered its response - it normally has nothing more to say to you. Short of re-opening the connection and reading it again (in-efficient unless you expect the response would have changed).

When you open the url, read the data, then re-use the data each time instead, eg:

```
url_data = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com').read()
do_something_with(url_data)
do_something_else_with(url_data)
```

As a note: Using regular expressions to extract data from HTML is at best a nightmare - look at a proper HTML parsing library such as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: I am expecting the response to change and hence the re-opening

Comment: @Matt do you definitely re-open it? Can you show where you open (and re-open) in your code?

Comment: I just call the Titles() again, do I need to state a re-open function?

Comment: @Matt once you do `titleread = titlerequest.read()` - that's it - `titlerequest` is exhausted... you need to make sure that `titlerequest` is re-opened and `.read()` again to receive new data. The reason I asked for the code was it's not clear where you're opening `titlerequest` to start with... (it appears to be global to `Titles` which has a bit of a code smell to it)